# Power Query check if any number is a linear combination of a subset of remaining numbers

Tags: powerquery

I have a dataset made of prod names (coming from local countries' databases) and in columns, all numbers parsed out of their names.

I am building a data mapper that would reconstruct product names to the standard used in central database. Aka ProdName Size PackSize [mix optional]

Prod Size = SUM ( Size(i) x NumPacks(i) ), i=[1,10]

Example of data (number of columns can be anything between 1-10):

```
ProdName|num1| num 2 |num 3 |num 4|num 5 | num 6 | num 7 | Desired Output
Prod1   | 5  | 20    | 2    | 25  | 2    | 30    | 120   | Prod1 120g pack of 5 (mix)
Prod2   | 2  | 200   |      | 400 |      |       |       | Prod2 200g pack of 2
```

The challenge is that some numbers will be irrelevant, i.e. traces of barcode, discount, parts of brand names.

I need to find a way to identify

1. Is any of the numbers a linear combination of a subset of others.
2. If so, and number of regressors is more than 1, then return a total size, total count of packs, and "mix". 
   Prod 1 scenario would return **Prod1 120g pack of 5 mix** (because 120 = 20x2+25x2+30, and 5 is the total number of packs 2+2+1).
3. If number of regressors is only 1 (i.e. count of numbers 3 or less), I want to return the regressor's (not total!) size and packsize. 
   I.e. Prod 2 scenario: return name is **Prod2 200g pack of 2**  (and not ProdName 400 pack of 2)

I am building a set of helper columns. For now I only have an idea how to work out the case of Prod2, when there are 3 or less numbers. I'm searching for a solution, but the plan is:

- get numbers for each row into a list excluding blanks (this is what I'm at now)
- calc the MAX and check if other numbers when multiplied = MAX
- assign smaller num to pack size, 2nd large num to Size (and ignore the MAX)

I am not sure yet about the Prod1's complex case yet.

Comment: I think the question will be easier to understand and more likely to get an answer if you can post sample output and the helper formulas that are currently used.

Comment: Hey thanks for a response. I have posted the outputs - in bold are the otuputs i need for the two cases i gave in the sample data. I am going to edit the question to put them into last col as Output though to be clearer.  As for the helpers, I'm trying to figure out how to get all the numbers for each row into a list excluding blanks. Then, get their MAX, and if the other two multiplied are equal to MAX, assign smaller to pack size and 2nd big to Size.    How I would do this for more than 3, i have no idea yet - hence asking for help. The task has turned out far more complex than i thought...

Comment: Prod 1 sounds similar to the subset sum problem, which is NP-complete. If you don't have that many numbers and the final sum isn't too large it might be fast enough to try every combination and find one that matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a good answer, one should know all types of possible combinations.
For the 2 examples provided, this will work:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Data"]}[Content],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "NonNullCount", each List.NonNullCount(Record.FieldValues(_))),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Output", each if [NonNullCount] = 4 then [ProdName] & " " & Text.From([num2]) & "g pack of "&Text.From([num1]) else [ProdName] & " "& Text.From(List.Max(List.Skip(Record.FieldValues(_),1))) & "g pack of "&Text.From([num1]) & " (mix)")
in
    #"Added Conditional Column"
```

Comment: Marcel, thank you for your answer. It's impossible to predict all combinations unfortunately, and the order of columns can be very random. However, I do realise that it's probably impossible to do what i need in a cell. Your solution helped me understand the key steps to solving a simpler subset of the challenge, so I'm going to mark it as answer. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

Here is another couple of ideas.
Getting a list of values, adding max and min values, quickly analyzing list for a value (you can add your logic here):

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    AddValuesList = Table.AddColumn(Source, "ValList", (x)=>
                       List.SelectValues(Record.ToList(Record.RemoveFields(x, "ProdName")), 
                          (y)=> y <> null)),
    AddMax = Table.AddColumn(AddValuesList, "MaxVal", each List.Max([ValList])),
    AddMin = Table.AddColumn(AddMax, "MinVal", each List.Min([ValList])), 
    AddCnt = Table.AddColumn(AddMin, "ItemCount", 
              if List.Contains(List.Select([ValList], (x)=> x <> [MaxVal] and x <> [MinVal]) 
                               , [MaxVal]/[MinVal]) 
              then [MaxVal]/[MinVal] 
              else null)

in
     AddCnt
```